# HTTP 400 in IE with Spring Kerberos

Tags: java, spring, kerberos

I just implemented Spring Kerberos and everything works in Chrome and FF but in IE I am getting a HTTP 400 Bad Request error. There is no mention of a header being to long. I already upped the Tomcat Header size to 65k.

Maybe related is the fact that the Kerberos authentication works for some people and doesn't for others (i.e some people only receive a ticket but are not authenticated, others are perfectly authenticated). Is there any other client configuration which comes into play when using SPNEGO/Kerberos than which is listed in the [Spring Kerberos documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#browserspnegoconfig)

Edit: For completeness: I fixed it by adding the maxHttpHeaderSize parameter in my connector in server.xml. Previously I had packetSize instead of maxHttpHeaderSize.

Comment: IE falls back to sending an NTLM token, when no Kerberos token for the service could be obtained. Have you checked that indeed a Kerberos token is sent when you get the HTTP 400 response with IE?

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr:  One point of note:  IE falls back to Basic Authentication when Kerberos fails.  That's why you see the Credentials dialog pop-up box asking for username/password when Kerberos fails.  NTLM doesn't do that, it is an SSO protocol which will not present that box.

Comment: @T-Heron the pop-up box need not show up but with IE, but IE still participates in SPNEGO sending an NTLM token. With SPNEGO there is currently no way to enforce a specific token type.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr - I should have clarified.  My argument wasn't that IE can't participate in SPNEGO or can't send an NTLM token.  It was that if IE can't negotiation Kerberos authentication, then it will fail over to trying Basic Authentication.  What I didn't say before is, that while the web server might call this an NTLM token, it actually isn't NTLM.

Comment: Further - Please provide a reference which contains a proven, reproducible example of failing over from Kerberos to NTLM.  All SPNEGO implementations that I know of fail over from Kerberos to Basic Auth or NTLM to Basic Auth, but not Kerberos to NTLM.  I used to think Kerberos to NTLM failover was possible myself, but after a lot of research and failed attempts to reproduce, I came to the conclusion that its not.  There's not a lot of good documentation on this particular situation, and a lot of mis-leading ones.  I'm willing to be proven wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. IE was not sending anything since the header size was too big for Tomcat. I increased the httpHeaderSize parameter of one of the connectors and everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the header was too big for Tomcat so I increased the httpHeaderSize parameter of one of the connectors. Before that, I had the wrong parameter (I used packetSize instead of httpHeaderSize). Thanks for all the comments nonetheless.